Document Scanner (simple scan) give error
"Failed to scan"
"Error communicating with scanner"
This is despite it working perfectly well yesterday (before software update), being plugged in with the same cable to the same port.
I  have been having other problems with the USB ports.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have not provided us with any details about your distro and version of Linux, the make and model of the scanner, how it is connected, WiFi, Ethernet, or USB, any drivers you have installed, the app you are using to scan, etc. Edit your question and add these information.
